# JNI hell: UnstatisfiedLinkerror

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

I'm running a Java app on Windows that uses some native dlls.

I get an UnstatisfiedLinkError caused by: "Can't find dependent libraries".
I'm using the `-Djava.library.path` correctly, since on other computers it works just fine.

Also, I tried to use `Dependency Walker` and so now problem with dependencies.

Is there anyway to access the JNI error itself and figure out exactly which dlls are missing. I remind you, I'm on windows.

Comment: Newer versions of windows typically give you better context on what can't be found.  You might try setting `PATH` instead of `java.library.path` to ensure paths to *all* of your DLLs are included.  It'd help to identify exactly which libraries you're using, as well as their non-system dependency list.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer the question.  Please provide the file name of your native dll, the Java code you are using the load it, the location the DLL resides in and the path you are using for java.library.path.